# Remote-control plugin with Grails 2.4

Tags: grails, upgrade, remote-control

Is anyone using the remote-control plugin with Grails 2.4.x?  I'm working on upgrading an app from 2.2.4 to to 2.4.3.  I've got it all working except for a few integration tests, and a bunch of functional tests.  In our functional tests, I'm getting the following error:

```
groovyx.remote.RemoteControlException: Error sending command chain to 'http://localhost:8080/<appname>/grails-remote-control'
    at groovyx.remote.transport.http.HttpTransport.send(HttpTransport.groovy:65)
    at groovyx.remote.client.RemoteControl.sendCommandChain(RemoteControl.groovy:114)
    at groovyx.remote.client.RemoteControl.exec(RemoteControl.groovy:73)
    at groovyx.remote.client.RemoteControl.exec(RemoteControl.groovy:67)
    at groovyx.remote.client.RemoteControl.call(RemoteControl.groovy:81)
    at PatientTests.oneTimeSetUp(PatientTests.groovy:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/<appname>/grails-remote-control
    at groovyx.remote.transport.http.HttpTransport$_send_closure1.doCall(HttpTransport.groovy:62)
    at groovyx.remote.transport.http.HttpTransport.send(HttpTransport.groovy:53)
```

I am using the 1.5 version of the remote-control plugin.  Any ideas or insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem today with Grails 2.4.3 and remote control 1.5

I initially thought the issue was related to https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10661

In my case, it was simply that I had a disconnected grails instance already running on port 8080 that I wasn't aware of.

Killing the errant process solved the issue for me.

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Peter